# Laravel multiple many to many

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.4

I am using many to many relation. i want to set two value for this attribute.

product,

attributes,

attribute_product => `product_id,attribute_id,value`

[image]

I know it's wrong , but I want to show you that i want

```
$product->attributes()->sync([
            1 => [
                'value' => 'sky'
            ],
            1 => [
                'value' => 'night'
            ],
        ]);
```

**Update 2**

```
Schema::create('attribute_product', function (Blueprint $table) {

$table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('attribute_id');
$table->text('value')->nullable();
$table->integer('devalue_id')->nullable(); // value id 

$table->primary(['product_id', 'attribute_id', 'devalue_id']);

});
```

**Update 1**

I need to set sky,night

```
product_id  attribute_id      value       devalue_id
1           1                 sky         1
1           1                 night       2
...
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase?

Comment: @ImAtWar https://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-149283  This laptop has multiple value for attributs:

Comment: usage: multi-media , Narrow and light . how does it save this values

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson i'v tagged 5.4

Answer (score 3):

For something like this I can see 2 options:

**1.**

Manually attach and detach the records that you want. This may lead to issues with how you retrieve the data though as it will return multiple of the same attribute, however, you could potentially use `groupBy` on the collection to get around this issue (if it is one for you).

**2.**

You could store a JSON object in the value column on the pivot table. This would allow you to have multiple values for the same attribute. To do this you can create an `AttributeProductPivot` class (or whatever you want to call it) that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` and add a casts property to it i.e.:

```
class AttributeProductPivot extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'value' => 'collection', //or object or array
    ];

}
```

Then change your `attributes()` relationship to be:

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class)
        ->using(AttributeProductPivot::class)
        ->withPivot('value');
}
```

The `using()` allows you to set a different Pivot Model that the default one. Don't forget to do the same for the inverse relationship if you need to.

You would need to cast the `value` attribute to json yourself when attaching/syncing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean save sky ,night in a field as json ?

Comment: {"Sky","Night"} is it easy for mysql to search in values ? get posts where attribute is sky

Comment: What should I do with my primary keys - 2 / 3 ?

Comment: @danialdezfooli No, it isn't that easy to search. If you are using mysql 5.7+ then you could change the column value from text to json and then you would be able to query it but it is much slower. I was only saying as a potential alternative but if you're need to search it probably wouldn't be. From the look of your table structure you're trying to create something similar to EAV. I would suggest looking in to something like that https://github.com/IsraelOrtuno/Eavquent/tree/3bd12b0b5cb0014099bb05c9af2a42705e403afe and https://lacke.mn/building-an-entity-attribute-value-system-part-i-understan

Comment: ...If you do try and go down the eav route I would suggest using polymorphic relationships to link your products to their attribute values.

Comment: i'v made \App\AttributeProductPivot.php but => `Class '\App\AttributeProductPivot' not found`

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: oh the namespace :D

Comment: it's working as 'json' , but could help me about my codes , without json ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, so I'll address two different scenarios.

1: Create an attribute and link it to a product. In this case, you have a product and know the name of an attribute, but it's not in your attributes table yet. It would look something like:

```
$product->attributes()->saveMany([
   new App\Attribute(['title' => 'sky']),
   new App\Attribute(['title' => 'night']),
]);
```

2: Attach an existing attribute to a product. In this case, you have the attribute already in your attributes table and have looked it up. It's pretty similar, actually, except for finding the attributes.

```
$attribute1 = Attributes::where('title', 'sky')->first();
$attribute2 = Attributes::where('title', 'night')->first();

$product->attributes()->saveMany([
    $attribute1,
    $attribute2,
]);
```

Comment: $product->attributes()->detach();
        $product->attributes()->attach([...]) ; i'm doing this now

Comment: Rather than doing the detach first, you can actually just use $product->sync([...]), which will get rid of any attributes that aren't in the array and add any that are. A bit tidier in the code. :)

Comment: Ah, I've not used a three-field primary key before. If I need a primary key on a pivot table, I typically just make a unique id field, because I'm lazy. :D